disk encryption in ubuntu 24.04 LTS
When we do manual disk configuration for installation with 24.04 LTS, there is no option to encrypt partion (not disk). There is one option to erase whole disk rather than partition and it also requires to disable windows bitlocker. There are many posts that are in this context but none answers about future support. I currently have 22.04 LTS and it has root encrypted and I want to continue on same line. If we upgrade to 24.04 from previous installation, then it will still have encrypted partition. So, it does not make sense option for encryption for partition is not supported. Here is the question - if partition encryption with dual boot is not supported, then will it be added in future or shortly or it is a missing feature like bug that will be addressed soon?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

edited for question in post

You could solve this problem by installing Ubuntu Unity 24.04 instead of the default flavor of Ubuntu 24.04. In particular, when doing manual disk configuration, you would need to recreate the partition that is intended to be encrypted (it won't work if you just reformat an existing partition), and select ex4 or other partition formats, and then select encrypt.
Note that if your /boot is not in an encrypted partition, the installer might show a warning. However, grub might not work if /boot was in an encrypted partition, so you should probably just ignore the warning.
Once installation is done, you could run sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop to install the desktop environment of the default flavor.
References:

How to install GUI desktop on a server?
Encrypted /boot install


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
